# EC2 - Windows Server - Not openning 41890 port

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016, access-control-list, network-security-group

I have a client' EC2 Instance with Windows Server 2016 Datacenter OS, IIS 10.0 running an ASP Classic Web Site and an Elastic IP associated. Everything ok until there. The set up of the web server which is running in port 80 is ok but my main problem came when ASP Classic system tries to connect to an external MYSQL database in port 41890.

I have checked the instance security group and allowed HTTPS (443 - for migrating the site to https after resolving this issue) and this custom port which I need to connect to DB. But Even I allowed this, the Network ACL is allowing all incoming traffic and I have opened up this port in Windows Firewall when I try to connect in MYSQL Workbench in this DB it gives me error 10060 but when I do in my own computer it connects successfully.

So I think the problem is not with the MYSQL' external access configuration since it connects from my computer and the outbound/incoming traffic through this port buy my configurations seem to be correct and I don't know where might be the issue.